# Exchange Server 2010 (local) migrated to Office 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, migration, exchange-2010, office365

We have a Exchange Server 2010 and we want migrate to Office 365. Our exchange are located in LAN not expanding in WAN.

First question - To make migration, we must expand this to WAN? We try to use migration tool from Office 365, but the RPC record has not been recognize.

We have try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2389390 but without any success.

Comment: Have you contacted Office 365 support for assistance?

Comment: Not yet, because I'm not sure that my configuration is correct. On youtube/google I found many information - like: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNYbE5oS4gE - but I've got an error on stage when I put a RPC proxy record. I will send request to Office 365 support.